# Breaking size limitation for lycanthropy

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, creature-size

I'm trying to find any way to get around the whole "you can only choose an animal up to 1 size category different than yourself" rule for Lycanthropes, Shifters who are going Weretouched Master, and characters entering the Primeval prestige class from Frostburn.

So far, the closest thing I have come up with is being a Goliath (or using the Old Blood feat from Bastards & Bloodlines and choosing Goliath), then going Barbarian 1st level and choosing the racial substitution Mountain Rage. My logic is that Mountain Rage makes me large while raging, therefore the size limitation can now be applied to large size rather than medium, so I can choose a Huge animal. But that would tie the shapeshifting specifically to rage, which I suppose I can live with, especially if I can convince the DM to houserule that shifting can work as a substitute for rage in this instance due to the reading on the Shifter racial entry for that ability.

Any idea how I could break that size restriction another way? Any idea how I could stay a medium size character and use the listed template or race and class ability to transform into something larger than huge?

(I don't want to play a Druid because they have no real connection to the animals they turn into and are able to just turn into any animal they come across, so the feel isn't really the same. It's fluff reasoning I know but the whole reason I'm going with the stated races and classes is that the character is connected to/related to/a part of that particular animal.)

Comment: The prestige classes weretouched master and primeval use totally different mechanics from lycanthropy (although you're right in that the size thing remains). You might want to open another, separate question for those. (*How can I assume a larger alternate form?* or something.)

Comment: Ok, I'll go ahead and post it a separate question and remove the edit then. Thanks again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A creature that contracts lycanthropy apparently does so instantaneously upon suffering a natural lycanthrope's bite and failing the Fortitude saving throw. The supernatural ability [curse of lycanthropy](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/lycanthrope.htm) says

> Any humanoid or giant hit by a natural lycanthrope’s bite attack in animal or hybrid form must succeed on a DC 15 Fortitude save or contract lycanthropy. If the victim’s size is not within one size category of the lycanthrope (for example, a hill giant bitten by a wererat), the victim cannot contract lycanthropy from that lycanthrope. Afflicted lycanthropes cannot pass on the curse of lycanthropy. (*MM* 176)

In the example above, oddly, a [wererat](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/lycanthrope.htm#wererat) in hybrid form is Medium and a [hill giant](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/giant.htm#hillGiant) Large; those *are* within one size category. So assuming Skip Williams means the wererat is in *animal* form, this means the curse of lycanthropy checks the potentially afflicted creature's size category *only* when the creature initially contracts the curse.<sup>1</sup>

That's your in.

So, although the DM may (and *should*) care, the curse of lycanthropy apparently doesn't care *how* the victim achieved the size category he had when the victim *became* an afflicted lycanthrope, nor does the victim's size category seem to matter *after* the victim's afflicted. He's an afflicted lycanthrope *now* with whatever form of lycanthropy he was afflicted with *then*, regardless of his actual, for-reals size category.

*Seriously*, talk this over first with the DM.

This means that, for example, if the DM determines the goliath racial trait powerful build counts toward the size categories of lycanthropic afflictions a goliath is subject to, were such a goliath *also* to be the subject of an effect like [*enlarge person*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/enlargePerson.htm), such a goliath would count as a Huge creature for lycanthropic affliction purposes. Then, if, while so virtually Huge, that goliath were bitten by a were-[roc](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/roc.htm) [storm giant](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/giant.htm#stormGiant) that was in hybrid form, *and* the goliath failed the Fortitude saving throw (DC 15), that goliath could become an afflicted were-roc. All assuming the DM is on board, of course.

Given the likelihood of a high Constitution score and the inability to voluntarily fail saving throws against anything but drugs, psionic powers, and spells, the affliction may need a few bites to take. A method of healing between bites might be wise.

It *will* be challenging for such a lycanthrope to breed with similar lycanthropes to produce natural lycanthropic offspring. I mean, if that's a concern.

Note that if a DM ever pits my PC against a gnome who we later learn had once inadvertently used a scroll of the 7th-level spell *giant size* [trans] (*CM* 109-10) to become Huge only to be bitten immediately afterward and contract lycanthropy so that we PCs now have to fight a Gargantuan 36-Hit Die were-[giant squid](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/squidGiant.htm) gnome, I am deleting this answer. Don't think I won't.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> The counter to all this is, of course, that Williams means the *animal* part of being a lycanthrope, and the typical [dire rat](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/direRat.htm) is Small. This puts a kibosh on the whole thing. But because we *want* this to work, we won't go there.

Comment: I'm now really tempted to post a copy of this, changing just a few lines: "Note that id Hey I Can Chan's DM ever pits his PC against [...], I am _not_ deleting this answer." XD

Comment: Ok, this answers 1 portion of my question, potentially 2. And a gigantic squid-Gnome sounds hilarious! But what about Primevals and the Weretouched Master leads to a related question I'm going to edit into the primary question. Thanks!