# How can I assume a larger alternate form?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class, creature-size, eberron, shapeshifting

The Weretouched Master prestige class from Eberron Campaign Setting and the Primeval prestige class from Frostburn have a size limit restriction on your alternate form. I'm wondering if there's any way to get around that without having to change my characters base size or using a different shape-shifting effect?

I want to be medium and be able to transform into something huge or gargantuan using these prestige classes. Specifically I'm looking to play a Saurian Shifter (*Dragon* 328) who can transform into something like a T-rex, spinosaurus (*Monster Manual II*), or maybe gigantosaurus (*Dragon* 318).

Comment: Related: [Breaking size limitation for lycanthropy](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67394)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suppose after all this time my best bet is to go with the same kind of answer in the related thread and/or the idea I gave in that other post. The Goliath race has a racial substitution for Barbarian called Mountain Rage which allows them to actually grow to large size while raging. And theres a class that let's you count as a goliath in Races of Stone as well as a feat in Bastards & Bloodlines a Guidebook to Halfbreeds. This is probably the best I'm going to find and I honestly think it'll work. Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Neither primeval nor weretouched master received any options, improvements, or extensions in any supplements beyond those in which they were originally printed. Their particular forms of shape-shifting are unique and not expanded upon by other classes or feats. They do not even qualify for master of many forms, the usual go-to solution to wanting to turn into something you usually can’t.

Weretouched master can only turn into the six animals listed. They never published additional animals for that list, much less added dinosaurs to it (not even when they published saurian shifters). The weretouched master is what you see in *Eberron Campaign Setting* and nothing more.

Primeval gets marginally closer, since primeval form “functions similarly to the druid’s wild shape,” but similar is probably not good enough to actually count as wild shape for prerequisites. That means options that would improve wild shape, and might work here, won’t work for the primeval. Moreover, the primeval’s inability to select new forms *ever* means that even if it *did* count as wild shape, you wouldn’t be able to pick a larger dinosaur because in order to qualify you have to actually have the class feature, but once you have it you’re locked in to your initial choice.

Master of many forms from *Complete Adventurer* is still your closest bet. Maybe your DM lets you use it on primeval form, and lets you use new forms as if primeval form was wild shape. But primeval form is still badly limited in uses per day, and requires taking most of your feats and setting them on fire (all three of those feats are awful).

You would be vastly better served by just being a druid, and taking master of many forms. It, too, requires a couple of terrible feats, but you get much more out of it. You will have more uses per day, far more options, and so on. If you really want to avoid druid spellcasting (even though it’s excellent), you can get wild shape as a monk (*Dragon* 324) or [ranger](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/variantCharacterClasses.htm#ranger), too. Or if you want to have a greater emphasis on being a shifter, shifter druids can use the quite-good moonspeaker prestige class from *Races of Eberron* (though honestly I think straight druid is probably better, but then, straight druid is better than most things). Also, kind of random, but the bloodclaw master from *Tome of Battle* has special features for shifters (though honestly they’re not really that good).

Answer (score 0):

- Polymorph as spell, spell-like ability, or item charge (battle sorcerer as a discount druid is common)
- Animal Lord- turns into giant constrictor (huge) from Complete Adventurer
- Shapeshifter- wild shape (huge) from Oriental Adventures
- Shifter- greater wild shape (gargantuan) from Masters of Wild
- Prestige classes based on having polymorph or the spell lesser polymorph self

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it seems I wasn't specific enough. I was hoping to use the 2 afformentioned classes to do the transformation due to purely fluff reasons. Aside from the Animal Lord, none of those have the connection to the animal that I was going for. That's why I chose those 2 classes. I was hoping to find a way around those specific classes restriction on size. I should've added that in the original question I suppose. Thanks though.

Comment: You'd also have to find a way around the 8 HD limit to get to T-Rex (18 HD). Weretouched Master has a very specific list to work from so RAW it's out, unless there's a work around. Perhaps a chain method might be allowed. Psionics Expansion augmented to increase 2 sizes from a djore would be one example. Still a polymorph effect would do it... Ask DM if a houserule or a effect per day item would be allowed.

Comment: Might be that using any other effect and role-playing it to be the feature you'd prefer would be the closest solution

Answer (score -1):

I would consult your DM for context homeruling on this or ,barring that, seek a magic item (Ring of Enlarge Creature for instance) that allows you to activate an increase in size besides your transformation.